# Streaming csv data to BigQuery from Pub/Sub subscription using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Exploring ETL process with GCP. I am using Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery template in Dataflow.

Message data in Pub/Sub Subscription is a csv format as below

> 53466,06/30/2020,,Trinidad and Tobago,2020-07-01 04:33:52,130.0,8.0,113.0

this leaves an error while loading to BigQuery Table. How to convert CSV data to JSON in the template?

Comment: Can you share the error? Can you detail how do you launch your Template?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you used [this template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubsubscriptiontobigquery) , which is able to be adopt only for JSON format strings in Pub/Sub subscription. the document also says that.

As far as I know, one of another ways is to customize [this code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) for CSV streaming data on your own.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I got that following transformation need to be added function 
But where to place this in the above template?

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!

While creating job using pub/sub subscription to Bigquery template, click on see option parameters. Where we can set .js file path and UDF function name.

[image]

Here is the JS code for transformation i.e, from CSV format to JSON format.

```
function transform(messages) {
  var values = messages.split(',');

  // Construct output and add transformations
  var obj = new Object();
  obj.SNo = values[0];
  var dateObj = values[1];
  // Date format in file is dd/mm/YYYY
  // Transform the field to Date format required for BigQuery that is YYYY-mm-dd
  obj.ObservationDate = dateObj.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2");
  obj.Provision_State = values[2];
  obj.Country_Region = values[3];
  obj.Last_Update = values[4];
  obj.Confirmed = values[5];
  obj.Deaths = values[6];
  obj.Recovered = values[7];
  // add object to JSON
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);

  return jsonString;
}
```